# Xcode continuous error [FirebaseFirestore]: Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Backfill Indexes: 0 changes (0 bytes):>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I have integrated **Firebase 9.5.0** in my **iOS** project via **Cocoapods**.
I am using **Xcode 13.4.1**
I have following pods installed:

```
pod 'FirebaseCore', '~> 9.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseAuth', '~> 9.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', '~> 9.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseStorage', '~> 9.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseFunctions', '~> 9.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '~> 9.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '~> 9.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 9.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseAppCheck', '~> 9.5.0'
```

In my **AppDelegate.swift** I am initialising Firebase as follows:

```
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
FirebaseApp.configure()
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

When I run the app on iPhone11 Simulator, I get following continuous print in Console logs every few milli-secs, non-stop:

**[87345:733214] 9.5.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Backfill Indexes: 0 changes (0 bytes):>**

[image]

Which Transaction is it trying to commit? I have not invoked any Transaction yet. Why these never ending prints? Please help.

Comment: Seeing same thing now.  I am using Xcode 13.4.1 but am using firestore API via the swift package manager.

Comment: fixed it on both my iphone device and the simulator by simply removing the app altogether from the phone/sim and then rebuild/deploy to it again.

Comment: I've faced the same situation on both is and device. I am using Xcode 13.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Firestore iOS SDK v9.5.0. A fix has been merged and will be included in the next release. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10168 for details.

Answer (score -2):

fixed it on both my iphone device and the simulator by simply removing the app altogether from the phone/sim and then rebuild/deploy to it again. –